# android - TextViews with line break

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have TextViews and I want have their in rows as with line break. TextViews are objects with some functions. Their are words in array separated by comas. I want show its in a sequence with line break.

**This is my code:**

```
int i;
String p = "one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, ten";
String[] array = p.split(",");

LinearLayout groupLL = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams gLLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams mlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mlp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    newTextView.setText(array[i]);
    newTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    newTextView.setSingleLine(true);
    newTextView.setTextSize(20);

    groupLL.addView(newTextView, mlp);
}

ll.addView(groupLL, gLLP);
```

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**I have this:**

```
|one two three four five s|
|                         |
|                         |
```

**I want this:**

```
|one two three four five  |
|six seven eight ten      |
|                         |
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I change
newTextView.setSingleLine(true);
to
newTextView.setSingleLine(false);
then I have this:

```
|one two three four five six |
|                         sev|
|                          en|
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
newTextView.setSingleLine(true);
```

to

```
 newTextView.setSingleLine(false);
```

hope it will work my friend ......

Answer (score 1):

try to set setEllipsize for textviews

```
newTextView.setEllipsize(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

as you set true in this `newTextView.setSingleLine(true);` you need to set as false if you want text are wrap in next line

just `newTextView.setSingleLine(false);` change this in for loop

according to your code you are adding single element of your array object in new TextView everytime and there is not need to set this method for this you need to change your layout for this. If you are appending or your p string set in the single textview you getting as you want but with multiple textview you need change your layout.

for single textview

```
TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
newTextView.setText(p);
newTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
newTextView.setTextSize(20);

groupLL.addView(newTextView, mlp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set following to false instead of true to enable wrapping `newTextView.setSingleLine(true);`

Comment: Have you tried just inserting \n at the places,where you want a line break ?

Comment: No - because I don't know where I want line break. I don't know what is in String p. Line break must be on right-end of screen.